# ActiveMQ Artemis automatically logs my user out of console

Tags: authentication, activemq-artemis

I deploy ActiveMQ Artemis 2.20.0 with a user & password for the web console but once login is attempted the server logs show that the user is automatically logged out. I attach the server logs here:

[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't add images of logs. Please add the actual text of the logs. Not only is this easier to read, it is more helpful for other users because the actual text can be indexed and searched later.

Comment: Justin...the console is logging out the user automatically....

Comment: I do not know how to reproduce this .. It just will not login ... version is 2.20

Comment: Justin - what is hawtio ?

Comment: Check out https://hawt.io/. It is the component we use as the basis for the web console.

Comment: Ok..I also have a cluster now but only see 1 broker in the web console (i have 4 pods) - I can open a new post for that

Comment: According to the logs, every logout occurs at least a few minutes after the previous login.

Comment: Hi Justin... that is because I repeat the attempt to login .... forget about clusters showing for now ..I need to sort my console login and the console functions thx

Comment: What you're describing is not clear from the logs, and the logs are the only evidence you've provided in your question. Please provide clear evidence and a clear description of *exactly* what is happening. Without such detail not much help can be provided.

Comment: Basically there is no login.. I have console issues but testers are saying that client connection to port 61616 is working... I just need the console working to confirm

Comment: Hi Justin - see below that I have answered my own question

Comment: If you've answered your own question you need to mark the answer as correct to help others who might encounter this issue in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that a HA deployment of ActiveMQ Artemis (4 Pods in a cluster) in Kubernetes should be exposed using LoadBalancer (or Nodeport) but not Ingress. The Ingress exposure is not stable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The [ArtemisCloud.io](https://artemiscloud.io/) operator uses ingress to expose the web console of ActiveMQ Artemis and I'm not aware of any known issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hawtio uses a global session id so you can not access concurrently to multiple broker consoles. When you try to access to a second broker console you will get disconnected from the first broker console.